# more than one question per post

Tags: discussion

We've been enforcing a **one question per post** rule that is not clear at all on the help section. Nowhere in the info does it say that.

The rule makes a lot of sense so that folks don't have to guess if the answer for "editing curves" is on a question about "rendering video" for example.

Should this be added into the tour or or the text on this page https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/asking?

Comment: You might want to put this on global meta since ***we*** can't change the necessary sections and this really should be in there somewhere IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is completely agreed across all SE sites that you ask **one** question per question. (asking multiple questions is ok.)
[One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/278094)
[Can I ask only one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735/278094)

Now what to do to let new users know...

We can only edit this part, and the top site message on the tour page. 
[image: tour page]

Now in the help center we can only edit [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and a message at the top of the [main help page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help)

So my best suggestion is to comment on any new user's post that asks more then one question, and tell them (nicely) that you only ask one at a time.
If they do not edit, then DV.

Comment: To clarify the first paragraph, "posts" are called "questions" in SE jargon. So that translates to "please ask one thing per question (as in 'post'). If you have other things to ask, posting multiple questions (as in 'posts') is accepted".

Comment: @gandalf3 My 2 cents: Not all new users understand SE jargon though, and the majority of SE users *are* new users. And while it is fairly obvious in translation, skipping a translation step can only aid in communication. I feel the "one question per post" guideline could be more clearly outlined

Comment: @360ueck Hence my attempt at a clarification